# cannot build https://github.com/reactor/reactor-samples due to lack of availability of gradle dependencies

Tags: reactor, project-reactor

I cloned and imported the gradle project in eclipse with Gradle plugin.

but I am getting import errors for all reactor classes. None of the BUILD.SNAPSHOTS referred in the project can be found.

./gradlew compileJava
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.

  > Could not find io.projectreactor:reactor-stream:2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-stream-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-stream-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-stream-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-stream-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-stream-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-stream-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-stream-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-stream-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >   Required by:
  >     io.projectreactor.springone:reactor-samples:0.2.0
  >   Could not find io.projectreactor:reactor-bus:2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-bus-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-bus-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-bus-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-bus-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-bus-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-bus-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-bus-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-bus-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >   Required by:
  >     io.projectreactor.springone:reactor-samples:0.2.0
  >   Could not find io.projectreactor:reactor-groovy:2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-groovy-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-groovy-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-groovy-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-groovy-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-groovy-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-groovy-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-groovy-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/reactor-groovy/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-groovy-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >   Required by:
  >     io.projectreactor.springone:reactor-samples:0.2.0
  >   Could not find io.projectreactor.spring:reactor-spring-context:2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-spring-context-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     file:/Users/debasish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-spring-context-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-spring-context-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-spring-context-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-spring-context-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     http://repo.spring.io/release/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-spring-context-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-spring-context-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reactor-spring-context-2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >   Required by:
  >     io.projectreactor.springone:reactor-samples:0.2.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured an easier solution - its a pity that the sample itself doesn't ship with this entry configured. Ideally it should since the samples refer to snapshots.

just add a repository entry to point to spring snapshots and you find the build snapshots :)

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
  jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current samples require the 2.5 BUILD SNAPSHOT version of recator. Since this snapshot version is not available on maven central, you will have to build it manually so it is present in your .m2/repo before you can build the samples.

Comment: not a very convenient solution.. easier is to add the snapshot repo missing in the sample gradle file.

Comment: You are right, but even better if that would be in the repo: https://github.com/reactor/reactor/issues/610

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we just bumped to 2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and the extensions repo is lagging behind, it should be soon published on repo.spring.io at least, and with the M1 release this month anyway. Sorry for the inconvenience we just initiated this change last week.